# Finding all unique combinations of 1:n numbers without packages

Tags: r, combn

I need to create a function that provides me with all possible combinations of 1:n numbers. The argument of the function being n. I need to do this without using the combn function or any other pre-installed function within R.

[image]

This picture above depicts what I want to do. The bottom part is just using combn to check if the above function works.

I did the following but obviously it is not the right way currently.

```
pairwise_comp <- function(n) {

res <- matrix(nrow = 0, ncol = 2)
for (i in 1:n) {
  res <-rbind(res,cbind( i , i+1))
}


  return(res)

}
```

Comment: Is this homework? Also, you seem to be using several base R functions in your code.

Comment: yes it is for homework

Comment: The outputs match, don't they? What's the issue?

Comment: My current option does not match that output. The picture above is what i want to achieve, not what I have right now

Comment: Man... without the use of base R functions, how do they expect you to do this? so far you have `matrix`, `for`, `rbind`, `cbind`, `+`, `:`, etc. And that's assuming `function` and `return` are fair game.

Comment: Unclear. What output doesn't match? (Also unclear what can be done in R without "any other pre-installed function".) Furthermore teh code for combn is right there to look at. Just type the function name into the console (without the parentheses that Rstudio attempts to add.)

Comment: Building matrices or frames by repeatedly calling `rbind` is a really bad idea: while it does technically work, it scales very poorly and as such strongly discouraged. I suggest you pre-allocate it with what is "known" as the number of rows ahead of time: `!n/(!k*!(n-k))`. (The R function `factorial` is useful here ... if you can use it. Otherwise, you can make your own factorial rather simply with `prod` or a `for` loop.)

Comment: when I say functions, I mean from packages such as combn, and functions like combn, perumutations etc

Comment: @cory [there's nothing wrong with homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/6296561) if they're asked right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to attack this, some efficient, some readable (subjective), not many are both.

For instance, you can do it *recursively*, like so:

```r
pairwise_recur <- function(n, start = 1) {
  if (n == start) return()
  nrows <- factorial(n) / (factorial(2) * factorial(n-2))
  res <- matrix(nrow = nrows, ncol = 2)
  rbind(
    cbind(rep(start, times = n - start),
          1 + start:(n-1)),
    pairwise_recur(n, start = start + 1)
  )
}
pairwise_recur(4)
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    2
# [2,]    1    3
# [3,]    1    4
# [4,]    2    3
# [5,]    2    4
# [6,]    3    4
```

But several things about this are less-efficient:

1. R does not do tail-recursion very well, so theoretically this could fill the call stack and exhaust R; and
2. This is doing what I suggested *not* to do in [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56529524/finding-all-unique-combinations-of-1n-numbers-without-packages#comment99642790_56529524) about calling `rbind` iteratively.
3. It is error-prone: if you call with `n < start` or `n==0`, then it will fail.

And quite possibly:

4. If you are not able to use `factorial` in this fashion, you can equivocate it with `prod(1:n)`. The remaining functions below will use this `prod` method, over to you which is preferred.
5. Both `factorial` and `prod` will start failing with really high `n`, likely well beyond the limit you are going to use for this assignment. At those numbers, it will likely be necessary to go into the `gamma` realm, more-efficient calculations for high-`n` factorials (and likely necessary until R is fully 64-bit-integer friendly).

---

An iterative that fixes some of that might be

```r
pairwise_iter <- function(n) {
  nrows <- prod(1:n) / ( prod(1:2) * prod(1:(n-2)) )
  res <- matrix(nrow = nrows, ncol = 2)
  r <- 0
  for (i in 1:(n-1)) {
    for (j in (i+1):n) {
      r <- r + 1
      res[r,1] <- i
      res[r,2] <- j
    }
  }
  res
}
# same output
```

And frankly, one can get rid of the `r` counter with some clever math on `i` and `j`.

But it is still prone to problems when `n < 3`. This can be mitigated with:

```r
pairwise_iter2 <- function(n) {
  if (n <= 1) return(matrix(nrow = 0, ncol = 2))
  nrows <- prod(seq_len(n)) / ( prod(1:2) * prod(seq_len(n-2)) )
  res <- matrix(nrow = nrows, ncol = 2)
  r <- 0
  for (i in 1:(n-1)) {
    for (j in (i+1):n) {
      r <- r + 1
      res[r,1] <- i
      res[r,2] <- j
    }
  }
  res
}

pairwise_iter2(0)
#      [,1] [,2]
pairwise_iter2(1)
#      [,1] [,2]
pairwise_iter2(2)
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    2
pairwise_iter2(3)
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    2
# [2,]    1    3
# [3,]    2    3
```

One difference (which is pre-mitigated by the leading `if`/`return`) is the use of `seq_len`: if you want a sequence of length `n`, then `1:n` is accurate only as long as `n >= 1`. If `n` is 0, then `1:0` produces a vector of length 2, which is not what you should get; instead `seq_len(0)` returns a vector of length 0, which is more consistent.

---

This is still not "efficient" in the R way of doing things. For that, you can remove the inner `for` loop and assign by vectors:

```r
pairwise_vec1 <- function(n) {
  if (n <= 1) return(matrix(nrow = 0, ncol = 2))
  nrows <- prod(seq_len(n)) / ( prod(1:2) * prod(seq_len(n-2)) )
  res <- matrix(nrow = nrows, ncol = 2)
  r <- 0
  for (i in 1:(n-1)) {
    vec <- seq_len(n - i)
    res[r + vec, 1] <- i
    res[r + vec, 2] <- i + vec
    r <- r + length(vec)
  }
  res
}
```

It is actually possible to generate this *without* even the outer `for` loop, but it requires a bit more vectorized wizardry that is both outside the scope of this assignment and outside of my time to dedicate to this lesson.

Comment: Ugh. You literally did his homework for him... 3 times over

Comment: yeah, I know ... weak moment. Not entirely sure it's worth a downvote, but I can't completely argue the opinion that answers can be more "vague" than this.